# Convert a string to integer in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a variable read from a file:

```
%var%=13,145
```

I want to add this value to another value:

```
set /a %var%=%var%+5
```

but the result is `13+5`, not `13145+5`.

How can I delete this "," from  my string?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do not add commas.

```
set var=13145
```

And also, when assigning a variable, don't place it around `%`

```
set /a var=%var% + 5   (Or simply set /a var += 5)
```

Test:

```
@echo off
set var=13145
set /a var=%var% + 5
echo %var%
```

Output:

```
13150
```

#### Update

Another solution is to remove those commas with substitution:

```
set var=13,145
set /a var=%var:,=% + 5
```

Comment: These values are generated by another bat file and I can't modify that file.  Your solution is great, it resolves my problem.  Thank you a lot.

Comment: Assuming the comma is not in the value, then you could simply use `set /a var+=5`. But if the comma is there, then yes, you must remove the comma first.