# Batch file wont run operations between variables

Tags: batch-file, variables, math, operation

Im trying to create a calculator that will echo your body weight, body fat, fat mass, fat free mas, basal metabolic rate and calories needed in a day, based off input from the user for body weight and body fat, but the only output i get is that equations themselves, not the actual answer

```
@echo off
TITLE Caloric Intake Calculator

ECHO Caloric Intake Calculator

set /p bw=Input Body Weight in Pounds - 
set /p bf=Input Body Fat Percentage AS DECIMAL - 

::Exercise Variables Defined
set a=1.2
set b=1.375
set c=1.55
set d=1.725
set e=1.9

set g=500
set l=-500
set m=0

::Exercise Variables Input
ECHO How often do you exercise?
ECHO a) Little to None
ECHO b) Light Exercise (1 - 3 Days)
ECHO c) Moderate Exercise (3 - 5 Days)
ECHO d) Heavy Exercise (6 - 7 Days)
ECHO e) Very Heavy Exercise (Twice a day, Heavy Workouts)
set /p exc=Input the Corresponding Letter Value - 

::Surplus or Deficit
set /p ans=Enter "g" if you would like to gain weight, Enter "l" if you would like to lose weight, Enter "m" if you would like to maintain - 

::Calculations
set fm=%bw%*%bf%
set ffm=%bw%-%fm%
set bmr=370+(9.8*%ffm%)
set dcn=%bmr%*%exc%
set cal=%dcn%+%ans%

ECHO Body Weight = %bw%
ECHO Body Fat = %bf%
ECHO Fat Mass = %fm%
ECHO Fat Free Mass = %ffm%
ECHO BMR = %bmr%
ECHO Calories Required = %cal%

PAUSE
```

and the out put is this

```
    Body Weight = 151.2
    Body Fat = .16
    Fat Mass = 151.2*.16
    Fat Free Mass = 151.2-151.2*.16
    BMR = 370+(9.8*151.2-151.2*.16)
    Calories Required = 370+(9.8*151.2-151.2*.16)*c+l
    Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: I'm not sure on this but I think your sets have to use `/a` and not `/p` check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25166704/convert-a-string-to-integer-in-a-batch-file for a simple example of maths based on user input, I think you will also require `/a` for the `calculations` section as well

Comment: In addition to what Barkermn01 said about using `set /a` instead of `set` for math, you're also going to run into an issue with the calculation itself because batch can only handle integers. I'd recommend powershell or vbscript for this, since both of those can use decimals and they're both built in to Windows as well.